# Unable to create JOURNAL_VERSIONS table for jackrabbit in Oracle. {tablespace} variable is not resolved

Tags: oracle11g, jcr, jackrabbit

I have been trying to configure Jackrabbit with Oracle. I get an exception while the schema check is performed for the version table in cluster.

While the cluster configuration is being initialized it calls the `init()` method in the `DataBaseJournal` class. In there it calls `checkLocalRevisionSchema()`; That method in turns call `CheckSchemaOperation.run()` to check whether the LOCAL_REVISIONS table exists if not it creates it. At first time it does not have the table so it tries to create the table with:

```
create table ${schemaObjectPrefix}JOURNAL (
  REVISION_ID number(20,0) NOT NULL,
  JOURNAL_ID varchar(255),
  PRODUCER_ID varchar(255),
  REVISION_DATA blob
)
${tablespace}
```

Before executing the query the variable `${schemOBjectPrefix}` is replaced with `PBVP_Journal` but the `${tablespace}` is not being replaced. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My file system and persistence manager configuration looks like:

```
<Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
 <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
 <param name="url" value="java:/jcr/repositoryDB"/>
 <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="PBVP_version_"/>
 <param name="schema" value="oracle"/>
</FileSystem>
<PersistenceManager  class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
<param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
<param name="url"  value="java:/jcr/repositoryDB"/>
<param name="databaseType" value="oracle"/>
<param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="PBVP_version_"/>
<param name="bundleCacheSize" value="32"/>
<param name="tableSpace" value="default"/>
</PersistenceManager>
</Versioning>
```

My cluster configuration looks like

```
 <Cluster id="node1" syncDelay="2000">
                          <Journal   class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.journal.OracleDatabaseJournal">
 <param name="revision"  value="${rep.home}/revision.log"/>
 <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
  <param name="url" value="java:/jcr/repositoryDB"/>
   <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="PBVP_journal_"/>
  <param name="databaseType" value="oracle"/>
  <param name="schemaCheckEnabled" value="false"/>
    <param name="tablespace" value="default"/>
                          </Journal>
           </Cluster>
```

Comment: You seem to have lost some of the values for the FileSystem parmaeters. What is the precedence for parameters that are set in those three configurations, and are there any others?

Comment: This is how my file system config look slike                                                                   <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.OracleFileSystem">
   <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
   <param name="url" value="java:/jcr/repositoryDB"/>
   <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="PBVP_version_"/>
   <param name="schema" value="oracle"/>
  </FileSystem>

Comment: OK, I've edited that in to the question to it's readable. It doesn't have its own tablespace parameter any more. The PersistenceManager does but as tablesSpace, with the S capitalised. But if you're really seeing the `PBVP_journal_` prefix rather than `PBVP_version_` then the Cluster seems to be taking precedence anyway? Are you sure Cluster is being used?

Comment: Thanks for your response and editing the question, I have tried to format I could not.  I am not sure what you mean the cluster is used ? We do use this in cluster environment. At the moment I am running on standlone

Comment: You have different values in the Cluster and PersistenceManager (and FileSystem) settings. `tablespace` is only set in Cluster. If you're running standalone are the Cluster settings relevant, and used? You should be able to tell as `schemaObjectPrefix` has different values. I can't quite tell if you really see `PBVP_Journal_`, or if it's just substituted with *something* and you typed the wrong value in the question. Since `tablespace` isn't resolved, it sounds like the Cluster settings aren't used, or it's using cached values, maybe.

Comment: In the DatabaseJournal Class when it tries to check/create the LOCAL_REVISIONS table it calls the method checkLocalRevisionSchema(). It makes the call to    new CheckSchemaOperation(conHelper, localRevisionDDLStream, schemaObjectPrefix
                + LOCAL_REVISIONS_TABLE).addVariableReplacement(
            CheckSchemaOperation.SCHEMA_OBJECT_PREFIX_VARIABLE, schemaObjectPrefix).run();   Which doe snot replace {tablespace}

Comment: It definitely points to Cluster, I can see that schemaObjectPrefix is replaced with PBVP_journal I have double checked it

Comment: Alex any more ideas ?

Comment: Not really, sorry. Seems to match an example file I found somewhere yesterday. Only thing I can think of really is that it's picking up a cached config, or a different version of the config file. I assume just creating the table manually isn't really the answer for you.

Comment: In the jackrabbit code clearly it is not trying to resolve the tablespace variable and there is not any method to override isn't it a bug in Jackrabbit ?

Comment: Finally now I know what is going on.The Jackrabbit configuration loading mechanism goes through two routes
1. When jackrabbit is deployed for the first time it executes table creation statements through the class OracleDatabaseJournal which is aware of ${tablespace} so it resolves it.
2.When it is deployed second time and the first deployment fails it executes through DatabaseJournal class which is base class of OracleDatabaseJournal it does not know about ${tablespace} so it does not resolve it.

Comment: When I debugged I was following the second route so I concentrated on why does not it try to resolve the ${tablespace} in the sql statement.
It should not take the second route if the first deployment is success. In our case the first deployment failed because of the length of table name.
If we change the length of the table name it deploys ok so it should never come to second scenario

Comment: I wish I could answer my own question, I can't find a way. Could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally now I know what is going on.The Jackrabbit configuration loading mechanism goes through two routes

1. When jackrabbit is deployed for the first time it executes table creation statements through the class OracleDatabaseJournal which is aware of ${tablespace} so it resolves it.
2. When it is deployed second time and the first deployment fails it executes through DatabaseJournal class which is base class of OracleDatabaseJournal it does not know about ${tablespace} so it does not resolve it.

When I debugged I was following the second route so I concentrated on why does not it try to resolve the ${tablespace} in the sql statement. It should not take the second route if the first deployment is success. In our case the first deployment failed because of the length of table name. If we change the length of the table name it deploys ok so it should never come to second scenario